# Including Quote PDF in another visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce, quote

Some background; we are on Salesforce Salescloud and don't have CPQ & Billing. We want to add a document at the bottom of our Quote PDF. I found merging PDFs in Salesforce is not an option considering the complexity. We can convert the document to HTML content.

I generate the Quote document in the following way:

```
    public PageReference generatePDF(){

        Id QuoteId = (Id)ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
        String templateId = (String) ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('template');      
        
        //delete previous quote if present
        deletePrevious(QuoteId);
        
        //This Url create the pdf for quote
        String quoteUrl = '/quote/quoteTemplateDataViewer.apexp?id=';
        quoteUrl= quoteUrl  + QuoteId;
        quoteUrl= quoteUrl +'&headerHeight=30&footerHeight=30&summlid=';
        quoteUrl= quoteUrl +templateId;
        quoteUrl = quoteUrl+'#toolbar=1&navpanes=0&zoom=90';
         
        //Create pdf content
        PageReference pg = new PageReference(quoteUrl);
         
        //Document object of quote which hold the quote pdf
        QuoteDocument quotedoc = new QuoteDocument(); 
         
        //Get the content of Pdf.
        Blob b = pg.getContentAsPDF() ;
        
        //content assign to document
        quotedoc.Document = b;
         
        //assign quote id where pdf should attach
        quotedoc.QuoteId = QuoteID ;
         
        //insert the quotdoc
         insert quotedoc; 
        
        Long startingTime = System.now().getTime(); // Num milliseconds since Jan 1 1970
        Integer delayInMilliseconds = 500; // One-second delay
        while (System.now().getTime() - startingTime < delayInMilliseconds)  {
            // Do nothing until desired delay has passed
        }
        return new PageReference('/'+(String)QuoteId);
    }
```

Can I include this page in another page somehow? In that way I can call `Blob b = pg.getContentAsPDF() ;` to create a pdf with both.

Is this possible?

Thanks!